# pdf of an uniform distribution in matlab?

Tags: matlab, uniform-distribution

I'm reading a book and I came across a problem in which I should generate a uniform random variable and use `hist, mean` and `std` to compute the $pdf$, $m_{v}$ and $\sigma_{v}$. Note: I have to normalize the `hist`. This is what I did

```
x = rand(10000,1);
m = mean(x);
v = std(x);
pdf = hist(x);
pdf = pdf./sum(pdf);
bar(pdf);
```

Is this correct? Also, I found this function in Matlab `pdf()` and when I use it as following

```
p = pdf('Uniform', x);
```

It gives me `NaN`. What is wrong?

Comment: Looks like the function pdf() needs more arguments from you. For 'uniform' distributions you can specify the lower and upper limits of x. The following worked for me:
pdf('Uniform',x,0,10000);

Comment: @eigenchris, Perfect!!. thanks a lot.

Comment: Pardon me, it looks like I misinterpreted what the function does.
p = pdf('uniform',0:0.01:1,0,1)
'Uniform' is the type of distribution. The 2nd argument is a list of possible values that the random variable can take on. I generated 100 numbers between 0 and 1 using 0:0.01:1 (0 by 0.01 to 1). The 3rd and 4th arguments are the upper and lower limits of the range of values we can take on, so 0 and 1 in this case.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a pdf, not a pmf, so your results in p will not sum to 1 since they are sampled from a continuous distribution.

Comment: @eigenchris, if I put `1` instead `10000`, the hist won't be normalized.

Comment: As far as I know pdf is same as pmf but different names.

Comment: The pdf (probability density function) is a continuous distribution, in which the area under the curve sums to one. If you were talking about a pmf (probability mass function), which is discrete and not continuous, the sum of all the samples would be one. pdf is normalized in area under the curve whereas pmf is normalized in the sum of all points (which can't have an area). If you want something more like a pmf, normalized to a sum, then you would have to divide p by the number of samples you took (I took 100).

Comment: Maybe I'm being too picky about the definition of pmf and pdf for what you're looking for. I think you just want to divide by 100. :P

Comment: @eigenchris, you mean I divide by the sum of data not the number of data? Isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15352/discussion-between-eigenchris-and-croco).

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: @CroCo You want to divide by the number of occurrences. You are estimating the PDF by calculating the relative frequency of an event occurring. For histograms, this will be the value of each histogram bin divided by the total number of samples. If you use the sum of the data, your PDF will not sum to 1 as is required.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85, Is what I did correct to compute the pdf??

Comment: @CroCo It's close enough. Since `rand` returns uniformly distributed numbers between 0 and 1, and `hist` will use the min and max values of the input data, you really want to specify the bin locations for the histogram explicitly. Since you are using 10,000 samples though, it probably makes little to no difference. Note that what you have is actually a PMF (discrete) and not a PDF (continuous). To approximate the PDF, I would integrate the normalized histogram and then estimate its derivative. You can always check that your results closely match those predicted by theory.